# What does this Scala syntax mean (_*)?

Tags: scala

I saw this Scala syntax and I'm don't understand what it means:

`val a: HashMap[String, String] = HashMap(b map {s => (s(0), s(1))} : _*)`

I understand that it takes a list of pairs and converts it to a hashmap keyed by the first element of each pair, and the value is the second element of the pair.
However, I don't understand how this syntax implies that, and what the _* means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `s => (s(0), s(1))` creates a tuple of type `(String, String)`. Secondly, `_` is a wild card for the aforementioned tuple's type `(String, String)`. Then, with `*` you indicate that it is a `vararg` (repeated parameter).

So in other words, it means that you pass an `Array` of type `_` with variable number of parameters (`*`) that was created from maping collection `b` into tuple `(String, String)` (represented as `_`).